# mice.reuse() question: Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): Missing left after imputation

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I am attempting to impute data in my validation set, which follows the MICE imputation model from my train set using mice.reuse(). Imputation is following data split as they'll be used to train/val ML algorithms. Data (n=720) is comprised of clinical and lab measurement data (numeric or factor).

See below the steps:

```
# first split data 

sample_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(data))
train_data <- sample(seq_len(nrow(data)), size = sample_size)

train <- data[train_data, ]
val <- data[-train_data, ]

# mice imputation - train set
train_imp <- mice(train, 
                  predictorMatrix = predM,
                  method = 'pmm',
                  m = 5, maxit = 10, print = FALSE, 
                  seed = 500)

# apply train data imp model to val data
val_imp <- mice.reuse(train_imp, val, maxit = 1)
```

After this step, I receive the following error message:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): Missing left after imputation
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

The data looks something like this:

```
structure(list(male = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("FALSE", 
"TRUE"), class = "factor"), age = c(55.7864476386037, 55.895961670089, 
41.0376454483231, 29.6563997262149, 57.2183436002738), bmi = c(36.6115389471026, 
31.5536591487683, 22.7903289734443, 42.5307689412473, 33.6484537734337
), waist_circum = c(126, 103, 91, 133, 105), bp_sys = c(147, 
NA, 100, 160, 135), bp_dia = c(82, NA, 60, 81, 70), t2dm = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), hdl = c(NA, 
1.35, NA, NA, NA), ldl = c(3.41, 3.28, 2.87, 3.7, 3.59), triglyceride = c(2.54, 
1.04, 1.55, NA, 3.43), cholesterol = c(5.08, 5.1, 4.35, 4.82, 
6.06), alt = c(41, 26, 48, 31, 31), ast = c(33, 28, 33, 21, 28
), ggt = c(33, 65, 42, 45, 26), alp = c(70, 79, 51, 88, 70), 
    platelet = c(156, 313, 308, 337, 186), hb = c(14.4, 11.5, 
    15.3, 14.5, 14.2), tsat = c(19, 18, 28, 25, 32), albu = c(4.9, 
    4.5, 5.4, 4.3, 4.6), egfr = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), ferritin = c(171, 70, 499, 156, 94), 
    pt = c(1.04, 0.98, 0.99, 1.12, 0.97), bili = c(11, 5, 6, 
    8, 14), timp1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), p3np = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), ha = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), glucose = c(5.7, 6.1, 5.4, 13.9, 5.1), insulin_fasted = c(29.8, 
    36.2, 4.9, 11.3, 14.5), hba1c = c(35.522, 58.475, 40.987, 
    79.242, 38.801), fibrinogen = c(NA, 5.9, 3.5, 5.9, 3.1), 
    fib_score = c(3, 0, 0, 0, 2), steatosis_score = c(1, 1, 3, 
    3, 3), inflam_score = c(2, 0, 1, 0, 1), balloon_score = c(2, 
    0, 1, 0, 1), fnash = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("FALSE", 
    "TRUE"), class = "factor"), f2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("FALSE", "TRUE"), class = "factor"), 
    f3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("FALSE", 
    "TRUE"), class = "factor"), nash = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("FALSE", "TRUE"), class = "factor"), 
    fib4 = c(1.84300333252591, 0.980635141316159, 0.63463649053119, 
    0.331915071889987, 1.54703279971167), proc6 = c(9.2, 5.5, 6.2, 5.9, 10.5
    ), proc4 = c(470.9, 298.5, 458.2, 336.7, 516.3), t2 = c(NA, 
    60.6857152393886, 48.2999977793012, NA, 93.842859513419), 
    i7 = c(NA, 113.817410696955, 123.560049194916, NA, 130.116414030393
    ), fibrosc_stiffness = c(14.1, 7, 5.2, 7, 8.8), prognostic_score = c(-1.908509, 
    -25.028315, -3.495727, -27.147848, -10.20379), probability_steatosis = c(NA, 
    0.77446951, 0.114093059, 0.654343677, 0.000105034), diafir.h = c(0.615568767767871, 
    0.534318429857294, 0.890916911895936, NA, 0.779479718924847
    ), gdf15 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I can't seem to work out the problem. Any tips here?

I've also tried to apply the ignore arguement in running MICE itself, but this seems to take a very long time.. any one else experience this?

Comment: we need to see some of your data;  use the dput(yourdata[1:10, ]) command to share the first ten rows; then edit your answer by including the output

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I've added a glimpse of the data. There are hundreds of vars so it is a snapshot of a few.